# Past emails not showing for single user

Tags: profile, sharing

I just got our last user onto LEX, and he needed help locating where past emails show that sales reps sent. I showed him past activities on the contact and account level, to my dismay, his view of past activities was empty. This is in reference to at least one particular contact/account btw. I'm able to see the two emails sent/logged from about two weeks ago, they were sent by a completely different user, so not this new LEX user or myself. The user having issues has view/modify all data, as well view/modify all data for all objects as well. I've checked the organization-wide sharing settings, account : public read/write, and activity : controlled by parent. I'm at a loss, all settings point to this user being able to see/modify any data they want.

Comment: Does the user have a filter active in the Lightning Activity Timeline?

Comment: Nope, date range set to all time, activities to show 'all activities', and every activity type is checked.

Comment: I've assigned the profile that the troublesome user has assigned to them, to another user, and I'm able to see the activities (the two emails in particular) without any issue on the contact object. I would assume then its not profile related.